Keeping Enumitem Item Number within the Shadowbox
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\shadowbox{%
\begin{varwidth}{.9\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[before=\itshape,leftmargin=*,font=\normalfont,label=\textbf{\arabic*}]
\item \lipsum[13]
\end{enumerate}
\end{varwidth}
}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\shadowbox{%
\begin{varwidth}{.9\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[before=\itshape,leftmargin=*,font=\normalfont,label=\textbf{\arabic*}]
\item[\bfseries30] \lipsum[13]
\end{enumerate}
\end{varwidth}
}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\shadowbox{%
\begin{varwidth}{.9\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[before=\itshape,leftmargin=*,font=\normalfont,label=\textbf{\arabic*}]
\item[\bfseries300] \lipsum[13]
\end{enumerate}
\end{varwidth}
}
\end{center}
\end{document}

with output:

QUESTION: How may I keep all the item numbers within their respective shadowboxes?
Thank you.

Is there only one item in each box?

@egreg In the actual document, there may be more than one item---but perhaps no more than three in any one box.

How do you want the result to be? Increase the indentation? How many digits can the label have at most?

@JasperHabicht The number of digits (in actuality) should not exceed two. If the indentation could be increased slightly---that would be great.

widest=300 ...?

I don't think you need a varwidth box here. Why don't you just use a \parbox.
As for the left margin, you can set widest*=99 to tell enumitem that the label will at most be two digits wide. Finally, I'd create a custom command to simplify typesetting.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in, paperwidth=5.5in, paperheight=8.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem,fancybox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{boxedenum}{+b}{}{%
    \shadowbox{%
        \parbox{.9\textwidth}{%
            \begin{enumerate}[
                before=\itshape,
                leftmargin=*,
                widest*=99,
                font=\normalfont,
                label=\textbf{\arabic*}
            ]
            #1
            \end{enumerate}%
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{boxedenum}
\item \lipsum[13]
\end{boxedenum}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{boxedenum}
\item[30] \lipsum[13]
\end{boxedenum}
\end{center}

\end{document}


If you want to reuse this enumerate style, you can also set up a custom enumerate style using \setlist.

Thank you kindly for this answer.

After the accepted answer was posted, I discovered that a reasonable facsimile can also be had with a tikz shadedbox:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,enumitem}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newmdenv[shadow=true,shadowcolor=black,font=\sffamily,rightmargin=8pt]{shadedbox}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{shadedbox}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\bfseries300] \lipsum[13]
\end{enumerate}
\end{shadedbox}
\end{document}

which produces:

